# Option Menu with Date Shows as 1969-12-31

Tags: php, mysql

I have an option menu that works properly when there are records to display. I sometimes have a new item that still does not have records and I would like the option menu not to display any dates. Instead it displays 1969-12-31.

```
<select name="selDate" id="selDate" onchange="formDate.submit()">
<option value="%">all dates</option>
    <?php
do {  
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_RecordsetDate['date']?>"<?php if   
($varDate_Recordset1 == $row_RecordsetDate['date']) {echo 'selected';} ?>><?   
php $dates=date('l, F d, Y',strtotime($row_RecordsetDate['date'])); 
    ?></option>
    <?php
} while ($row_RecordsetDate = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordsetDate));
$rows = mysql_num_rows($RecordsetDate);
if($rows > 0) {
  mysql_data_seek($RecordsetDate, 0);
  $row_RecordsetDate = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordsetDate);
 }
 ?>
</select>
```

How can I have the option menu display blank if no records or just state no date available?

Comment: In which format is the date stored in the database? Like what's the value of $row_RecordsetDate['date']?

Comment: It is just stored as yyyy-mm-dd ie. 2016-06-26

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="selDate" id="selDate" onchange="formDate.submit()">
<option value="%">all dates</option>
<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordsetDate)){
        if(isset($row['date'])){
             if(strlen($row['date'])){
                 echo '<option value="'.$row['date'].'"';
                 if($varDate_Recordset1 == $row['date']){
                    echo 'selected';
                 }
                 $date = date('l, F d, Y',strtotime($row['date']));
                 echo '>'.$date.'</option>';
             }
        }
    }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Almost works. Only problem now is that only 1 date shows in my option menu instead of several dates when I have records.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated. Solution works except that it only shows the date for the oldest record in the query and not all dates in the query for the option menu.

Answer (score 0):

Through trial and error, I came up with the following solution. I placed an if else statement in the option value.

```
 <option value="<?php echo $row_RecordsetDate['date']?>"<?php if ($varDate_Recordset1 == $row_RecordsetDate['date']) {echo 'selected';} ?>><?php $dates=date('l, F d, Y',strtotime($row_RecordsetDate['date'])); $rows = mysql_num_rows($RecordsetDate); if(!empty($rows)){
                echo $dates; 
            }else{
          echo ""; }?></option>
```

Below is the complete solution.

```
<select name="selDate" id="selDate" onchange="formDate.submit()">
      <option value="%">all dates</option>
            <?php
    do {  
    ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row_RecordsetDate['date']?>"<?php if ($varDate_Recordset1 == $row_RecordsetDate['date']) {echo 'selected';} ?>><?php $dates=date('l, F d, Y',strtotime($row_RecordsetDate['date'])); $rows = mysql_num_rows($RecordsetDate); if(!empty($rows)){
                echo $dates; 
            }else{
          echo ""; }?></option>
            <?php
    } while ($row_RecordsetDate = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordsetDate));
      $rows = mysql_num_rows($RecordsetDate);
      if($rows > 0) {
          mysql_data_seek($RecordsetDate, 0);
          $row_RecordsetDate = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordsetDate);
      }
    ?>
        </select>
```